# call 2 functions onClick event

Tags: javascript

I have a text field with PLUS + button to increase textfield value, at the same time i want the limit of (0 - 100). I dont want any one increase value more then 100 or less then 0.

I try below code which only work for add function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(){
document.getElementById("name").value++;
}
function limit(){
document.getElementById('name').value;
      if(this.value > 200){
           this.value = 200;
      }
      if(this.value < 10){
           this.value = 10;
      }
}
</script>

<form name="quiz" >
<input type='text' name='name' id='name'/>
<input type='button' name='plus' onclick="add();limit();" value='+'/>
</form>
```

And is it possible to increase value by 5 i.e instead of value++ can we use value+5 (i try it but not working)

Comment: @sp00m document.getElementById("name").value = value + 5; its not working

Comment: it's document.getElementById("name").value = document.getElementById("name").value + 5
or shorter:
document.getElementById("name").value +=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function add(){
x=document.getElementById("name").value;
x=Number(x);
x=x+5
document.getElementById("name").value=x;
}

    function limit(){
x=document.getElementById("name").value;
x=Number(x);
      if(x > 100){
           document.getElementById("name").value = 100;
      }
      if(x < 50){
           document.getElementById("name").value = 0;
      }
```

Comment: @Arif Happy to help. what kind of limit do you want

Comment: value should be between 0 and 100

Answer (score 1):

You could simply change your code to only call one function (combine the `add()` and `limit()`) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add() {
        var name = document.getElementById("name"); // Get the input (store in local var).
        var value = parseInt(name.value) + 5; // Store the new value locally.

         if(value > 100){
              value = 100;
         }
         else if(value < 10){
              value = 10;
         }

         name.value = value; // Set the new value.
    }
</script>
```

And then just call `add()`:

```
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' value="0"/>
<input type='button' name='plus' onclick="add();" value='+'/>
```

Additionally, you could make it more dynamic and send in the value to add as a parameter:

```
function add(numberToAdd) {
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var value = parseInt(name.value) + numberToAdd; // Use the parameter
    ....
```

And then call it like this:

```
<input type='button' name='plus' onclick="add(5);" value='+'/>
```

This way you can have more buttons with different values:

```
<input type='button' name='plus1' onclick="add(1);" value='+1'/> <!-- Will add +1 -->
<input type='button' name='plus2' onclick="add(2);" value='+2'/> <!-- Will add +2 -->
<input type='button' name='plus3' onclick="add(3);" value='+3'/> <!-- Will add +3 -->
```

Comment: thanks for reply but ur top script start with 5, then jump to 105 & then 200

Comment: @Arif That's how you wrote it from the beginning, but I updated the answer =)

Comment: @Arif Notice `value="0"` on the "name" input and the `parseInt(name.value)` in the add function.

Answer (score 1):

if you call the add function now, it will increment your value by 5
this will only be done if your current value is under 200 and over 10

```
function add() {
    var val = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if(val < 200 && val > 10) {
        document.getElementById("name").value += 5;
    }
}
```

with this solution, there is no need for a second function (e.g. limit)

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(howMuch){
  document.getElementById("name").value = document.getElementById("name").value+5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do simply this

```
function add(){
document.getElementById("name").value++;
limit();
}
```

Yes you can increase by 5.
Just do this:

```
document.getElementById("name").value+=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple solution to ur case is to use only one function that does everything u want... hope it will help u :)

```
function add() {
   var limit = document.getElementById("name").value();
   if (limit < 200 || limit > 0) {
     document.getElementById("name").value++;
     //or use this
     //document.getElementById("name").value = limit + 5;
   }
   else
     //anything here.
}
```